# A ways to define theorem about triangle area in OWL and apply it to triangles individuals

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, rdfs

I am new in semantic web technologies. So, my question is is it possible and how to define theorem about triangle area in OWL? For example theorem about area using three sides of triangle. Then, calculate the area of any arbitrary triangle using this theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do that via SWRL. There's an example in the [Stardog documentation](https://www.stardog.com/docs/#_stardog_rules_examples) similar to your question, calculating the area of a Circle. The example uses our rule syntax, but it's the same semantics as SWRL, so the example would still hold if you wanted to replicate it with plain SWRL using Protege.

Welcome to the world of semtech!

Comment: Thank you! Correct me if I am wrong..This rules is an operational semantics in additional to OWL? Right? And what theories do they support? I mean first order logic, arithmetics and other theories. Here I mainly concern about arithmetics of different numbers.

Comment: @SergeySintsov SWRL is basically an extension to OWL and therefore also based on first-order logic (FOL), i.e. set theoretic semantics. Like OWL is with it's underlying semantics based on Description Logics which itself is a decidable subset of FOL.